# nuxt3 .nojekyll not working on Github pages

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, github-pages

I'm having some trouble when I want to deploy my nuxt project to a github page.
I have added the `.nojekyll` file under the public folder, but after running generate, files with "_" still appear under public/static.  [image]
Here are some details of my code.

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/google-adsense": "^3.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^3.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.10.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "nuxt": "^3.9.1",
    "nuxt-simple-sitemap": "^3.2.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.33",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "vue": "^3.4.10",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/robots": "^3.0.0",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.5.1",
    "nuxt-jsonld": "^2.0.8",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7"
  }
```

nuxt.config.ts
I don't need to set baseUrl because I already have redirect.

```
  experimental: {
    payloadExtraction: false,
  },
  app: {
    buildAssetsDir: "/static/",

  },
  nitro: {
    preset: "github-pages",
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: [
    "@pinia/nuxt",
    "@vueuse/nuxt",
    "nuxt-simple-sitemap",
    "@nuxtjs/robots",
    "nuxt-jsonld",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss",
    [
      "@nuxtjs/google-fonts",
      {
        families: {
          "Noto+Sans+TC": [500, 700],
          Roboto: [500, 700],
        },
        display: "swap",
        download: true,
        overwriting: false,
        inject: true,
        preload: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
```

The two files `_plugin-vue_export-helper.x3n3nnut.js` and `_name_.LPWOZD9u.js` will still be generated, causing the website to not run properly after I deploy it to github pages.
[image]

Comment: .nojekyll file does not go in the public folder.  it goes in your root project folder

Comment: @yoduh I moved the .nojekyll file to the root folder, but after generate, these two files with "_" will still be generated under public/static.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
I found that nuxt3 is built using vite.
I add the following code to `nuxt.config.ts`

```
const INVALID_CHAR_REGEX = /[\x00-\x1F\x7F<>*#"{}|^[\]`;?:&=+$,]/g;
const DRIVE_LETTER_REGEX = /^[a-z]:/i;

export default defineNuxtConfig({

  vite: {
    build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
          // https://github.com/rollup/rollup/blob/master/src/utils/sanitizeFileName.ts
          sanitizeFileName(name) {
            const match = DRIVE_LETTER_REGEX.exec(name);
            const driveLetter = match ? match[0] : "";
            return (
              driveLetter +
              name.slice(driveLetter.length).replace(INVALID_CHAR_REGEX, "")
            );
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
...
})
```

After running `npm run generate` again, files or folders with "_" will no longer appear under the public folder, and they can be correctly deployed to github pages.